# Que significa esto en JAVA y como pasarlo a PYTHON

Tags: java, python

Tengo que pasar este código de Java a Python pero la verdad no se que es lo que hace:

```
String row = (String) sprite[i];
```

Tenemos que sprite es un vector y esto se encuentra en un ciclo `for`, por lo que mi variable `i` es la que va estar aumentando.

Comment: Que valores tiene almacenado el vector? Lo que estas haciendo ahi, es un cast para convertir el valor almacenado en el vector a un valor tipo String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa que la variable `row` esta obteniendo el valor `i` del vector `sprite` y que este valor fue convertido a un `String`.

Ejemplo:

```
int i = 0;
int sprite = [1,2,4];

// es igual a 1 pero con tipo String
String row = (String)sprite[i];
```

Y se puede traducir a python con:

```
row = str(sprite[i])
```